# apt-get — Specify source IP address

Tags: networking, apt, ip-address

Is it possible to specify the client's IP address (i.e. the source network interface, like eth0, eth0:0, eth0:1...) to which apt-get should bind when it has to connect to the network (for instance installing updates)?

I didn't find anything in the apt-get man's page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt-get` does not have this functionality, as it really does not (and IMHO should not) care about this. It will use your default gateway, you can change this in a few ways, one is the `route` command:

```
sudo route add default gw [gateway IP] dev [device name]
```